# How can I replicate PHP get_file_contents with NodeJS on encrypted data?

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, lua

When using PHP with `get_file_contents()` to read in a file that has been encrypted, it doesn't change any of the encrypted contents.

When replicating it in NodeJS though through `fs.readFile(file, "utf8")` or even `fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8")` the encryption is somehow manipulated as when being checked the same way as the PHP version it fails.

Reading in that same file without encryption works with `fs.readFile(file, "utf8")`.

I have tried ignoring encoding all together, swapping to `binary` encoding and nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to keep `fs.readFile()` or `fs.readFileSync()` from change encryption characters?

Comment: 1 - Read the file as binary rather than string;
2 - If you with to decrypt, use the compatible algorithm and the keys you used to encrypt it (encryption algorithms may be implemented in different languages, JS/PHP for instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the "utf8" parameter in `fs.readFile(file, "utf8")`.

It seems like the right parameter for you would be "latin1" or its legacy alias "binary" which communicates your intention more clearly.

You can check [the available encodings here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffers-and-character-encodings).

Comment: Binary is not deprecated. It explicitly says "The following legacy character encodings *are also supported*". Binary certainly communicates the intention more clearly in this case, since the bytes are not to be interpreted in any way, although ideally an ArrayBuffer should be used instead of strings.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted the "legacy" as "should not be used anymore". I corrected my answer including your comment, thanks for poiting it out.